# AWS User Pools - defAuthChallenge called without session identifier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've added a lambda function to my AWS User Pool `Define Auth Challenge`

When my iOS app tries to sign a user in, the `Define Auth Challenge` lambda is called. But the `event.request.session` parameter is an empty list `[]`.

There is [only one example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/customizing-your-user-pool-authentication-flow/) (it's a screenshot of part of a JavaScript lambda), but that expects `session` to be defined.

What do I need to define in my iOS app to have `session` correctly populated?

```
event = {
    u'userName': u'SET', 
    u'userPoolId': u'SET',
    u'callerContext': {
        u'awsSdkVersion': u'aws-sdk-ios-2.6.10', 
        u'clientId': u'SET'
    }, 
    u'region': u'SET', 
    u'request': {
        u'session': [], 
        u'userAttributes': {
            u'email_verified': u'true', 
            u'email': u'SET', 
            u'sub': u'SET', 
            u'cognito:user_status': u'CONFIRMED', 
            u'cognito:email_alias': u'SET'
        }
    }, 
    u'triggerSource': u'DefineAuthChallenge_Authentication', 
    u'version': u'1', 
    u'response': {
        u'issueTokens': None, 
        u'failAuthentication': None, 
        u'challengeName': None
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `session` in `event.request` is not set by clients.

For the first call of the Define Auth Challenge Lambda function, `session` is an empty list. Subsequent calls will populate `session`

With Python, a single-step custom flow `Define Auth Challenge` could take this form:

```
def handler(event, context):

    step = len(event['request']['session'])

    if step == 0:
        event['response']['challengeName'] = 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE'
        event['response']['issueTokens'] = False
        event['response']['failAuthentication'] = False
    elif step == 1 and event['request']['session'][0]['challengeName'] == 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE':
        event['response']['issueTokens'] = event['request']['session'][0]['challengeResult']
        event['response']['failAuthentication'] = False
    else:
        event['response']['issueTokens'] = False
        event['response']['failAuthentication'] = True

    return event
```